# SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services with Custom Viewer, Sort lost in Page Change

Tags: sorting, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2008, report

I'm working on a project where we're trying to migrate from SSRS 2005 to the 2012 (which it seems is not much enhanced from the 2008 R2 standard).    We're using a custom report viewer control that's interacting with the ReportExecution service to get rendered data and display it.

For a skeleton of our basic logic, we have:
If (Request to sort was sent)
  Set sort criteria in a dictionary collection (itemID and sortDirection) which is persisted in session.

--further down--

If (Sort Criteria Collection is not empty)
  Invoke ReportExecution.Render to render HTML (actual HTML is unused here, comment notes this is due to a bug.  appears to be needed because sorting stops working entirely when this Render stage is removed)
  Invoke ReportExecution.Sort to clear Sort criteria by using the first itemID in the sort list, sorted by None, sending True for clear flag (to clear all previous sorting criteria set)
  For Each item in Sort Criteria collection
    Invoke ReportExecution.Sort with current sort criteria, clear flag is False

--further down--

Invoke ReportExecution.Render to render report data in HTML to set as report pane content.

Under SSRS 2005 services, this code works fine, with sorts operating as they should and sorts being maintained as users move between report pages.

Under SSRS 2012 services, this code only somewhat works.  Invoking sorts with the sorting controls on the reports work, but when the report page is changed, the dataset returns to the unsorted order.

I've checked to see that the sort collection is being properly persisted between the time when the Sort is requested and when the Page Change occurs, which it is.  I've checked to see that ReportExecution's Sort method is being invoked, which it is.  I've checked ExecutionLog3 view in the SSRS database and I'm seeing rsSuccess status for my sort call on the page change.  I've checked to see if something is different about the Sort invoke when it's sent from the "user clicks sort button" context and "user clicks next page button" context, which it's not (content of the calls to the Sort method are identical in both contexts).

Even more curiously, SSRS seems to understand the sort that it should have applied, because if I've run a report and sorted by, say, user_name descending and then moved from page 1 to page 2, the result from Render returns the data for page 2 when unsorted but also has the sorted descending image on the user_name column.

With the current setup, the only way to see Page X of data sorted by Condition Y is to navigate to Page X, then set the sort criteria.  If you set the sort condition first, then navigate to Page X, the sort criteria is lost, and the only way to get it back is to set it again.  Since the report is already showing that the data is sorted by user_name descending, as an example, to get the sort to set properly you have to set the sort to user_name ascending, then set it back to user_name descending again, at which point you have the right data for the page with the sort properly applied.

I've tried modifying our core logic in a number of ways.  I've tried removing the Render before the Sorts are applied (breaks Sorting functionality entirely).  I've tried removing the dedicated None sort stage and setting the clear flag on our first sort, removing the extra layer of sort criteria that doesn't actually sort things (same result as before the change).  I've tried switching to the Sort2 and Render2 methods that were introduced after SSRS 2005 (no change).

I've read the Pragmatic Programmer, so I know the whole lesson about "select isn't broken", but I'm coming perilously close to having to make that conclusion as I run out of ideas.  Has anyone out there encountered this before who might have tips to help me figure out why this sort is seemingly being accepted by the SSRS services but disregarded when it comes to actually sorting the report's dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since I found my answer on my own, I'll go ahead and post this.

As it turns out, the custom reporting control was calling SetExecutionParameters on every page load.  It seems this was the culprit.  With SetExecutionParameters called even when they hadn't changed (first/previous/next/last paging controls, search in report, etc), I would get the described behavior where the Sort operation was reporting success but also displaying displaying the data in an unsorted way.

I modified the report to be saner with the report parameters, calling SetExecutionParameters only when the "Generate Report" button was used.  Adding that to a change I'd tried before, removing the weird dedicated None sort stage, Sort has gone back to working as expected.